# Xcode Organiser showing hang of 9780ms duration around GoogleMaps usage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps-ios-utils

[image]
As shown in attached screenshot, Xcode is detecting a hang of 9780 ms in my iOS App. Some additional details:

- GooleMaps iOS SDK version: 6.2.1
- iOS versions for which the above issue has been observed: iOS 16.3, 16.4, 16.5

Can someone help me find what's causing this long hang?

We have made sure that the thread executing the `GMSMapView` rendering is happening on the main thread and is not blocked.

Comment: Have you tried to use the Time Profiler in the Instruments app?

Comment: I tried Time Profile but not able to see Hangs section in it. I am using Xcode 14.3.1